# Replace nested field values in an object

Tags: javascript

I need to replace every `time` value in a nested object with a momentJS element of its value.

```
const input = {
  data: {
    sub1: {
      time: 1578857603218
    }
    sub2: {
      some: 'thing,
      foo: [{
        value: 123,
        time: 1578857603218
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

Right now my code looks very ugly, as I'm doing this manually as there are specific fields with an optional time value.

```
if (data && data.sub2 && data.sub2.foo && data.sub2.foo[0].time) {
  data.sub2.foo[0].time = moment(data.sub2.foo[0].time).toDate()
}
```

To do this in a more dynamic way, I see two options:

1. Pass something like an array/map with all optional time fields and replace them with a loop

Is there a better way to replace my `if` conditions to go through all relacing time fields?

2. Iterate through all keys

But this would not work for nested objects.

```
for (var prop in obj) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop)) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: You need it in vanilla js? And btw, is it possible to change data to array of objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the key value pair, then what you show as already in use is exactly what you should use. It is O(1), very quick, and essentially a single line.

Making that dynamic will require O(n) where n is the number of key value pairs, and will require several lines of code.

```js
const renderTime = input => {
  if (Array.isArray(input)) {
    input.forEach(el => renderTime(el));
  }
  if (typeof input === 'object' && !!input) {
    Object.keys(input).forEach(k => {
      if (k === 'time') input[k] = 'moment(input[k]).toDate()';
      else renderTime(input[k]);
    });
  }
};

const input = {
  data: {
    sub1: {
      time: 1578857603218
    },
    sub2: {
      some: 'thing',
      foo: [{
        value: 123,
        time: 1578857603218
      }]
    }
  }
};

renderTime(input);
console.log(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to deal with nested objects with an undetermined level of depth, think of recursivity

```js
const setTime = (object, time) => {
  for (let prop in object) {
    if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, prop)) {
       continue;
    }
    if (typeof (object[prop]) === 'object') {
      setTime(object[prop], time);
    }
    if (prop === 'time') {
      object.time = time;
    }
  }
  return object;
};

const input = {
  data: {
    sub1: {
      time: 1578857603218
    },
    sub2: {
      some: 'thing',
      foo: [{
        value: 123,
        time: 1578857603218
      }]
    }
  }
}

setTime(input, 666);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:) The secret is recursive loop

```
const input = {
  data: {
    sub1: {
      time: 1578857603218
    },
    sub2: {
      some: 'thing',
      foo: [{
        value: 123,
        time: 1578857603218
      }]
    }
  }
};


function changeTime(obj) {
  obj && Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
     if(key === 'time') {
       obj.time = moment(obj.time); // you have to use moment
     }

     if(typeof obj[key] === 'object'){
       changeTime(obj[key]);
     }
   });
}

changeTime(input);
console.log(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

This won't handle the case where the nested fields are in an array, but it should work for nested objects

```js
function replaceNestedValues(obj, targetVal, nextVal) {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, key) => {
    const value = obj[key];
    if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null) {
      acc[key] = replaceNestedValues(value, targetVal, nextVal);
    } else if (value === targetVal) {
      acc[key] = nextVal;
    } else {
      acc[key] = value;
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});
}
```

Example

```js
const data = { a: { b: 10, c: null }, d: null };
replaceNestedValues(data, null, '');
// => { a: { b: 10, c: '' }, d: '' }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to modify your property. The property can be present in deeply nested object or within array of objects.

```js
foo(entry: any | any[]) {
  if (Array.isArray(entry)) {
    entry.forEach(ent => this.foo(ent));
  } else if (typeof entry === 'object' && entry !== null) {
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(entry)) {
      if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null) {
        this.foo(value);
      } else if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        this.foo(value);
      }
      if (key === "time") {
        entry[key] = "changed"; // modified value
      }
    }
    return entry;
  }
}


this.foo(data);  // your object
```